# Hide a div to user role in one page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I would like to hide a particular div from a specific user role on a page of my site, I tried to insert the following code in the function.php file of my theme, but unfortunately it doesn't work, do you have any suggestions?

```
<?php
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'shop_manager', $user->roles ) ) {
?>
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    jQuery( "#hide" ).empty();
    
});     

    </script>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do you need JS for this? Why not completely remove the markup instead? Also, what **exactly** is not working with the given code?

Answer (score 0):

[functions.php is for adding php functions to your site.](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/#what-is-functions-php) If you wanted to print out HTML/JS in your theme, you would need to add this to your theme file (index.php or footer.php)

Place this code in your theme file and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the footer hook to inject your css/js code:

```
function your_function() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( in_array( 'shop_manager', $user->roles ) ) {
        ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
            jQuery( "#hide" ).empty();
        });
        </script>
        <?php 
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'your_function' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 
add_action( 'wp_head', 'callback_hide_div_onpage' ); // wordpress header action hook 
function callback_hide_div_onpage() {
  if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = $user->roles;
    if($roles[0] == 'student_role'){  // role name -> Student Role
    
      // When the Page with a post_name (slug) of "about-me" is being displayed.
      
      is_page( 'about-us' ){  // add specific page to hide a div using style 
      
      ?>
     
        <style>
          /* hide div using styling css option or you can used script for this as per requirement */
          .target_div{
            display:none !important;  
          }
        </style>
      <?php }

    }
  }
}
```